# How to remove bracket from JSON in Flask

Tags: python, json, list, flask

I want to remove one fo them bracket from JSON in Flask. I want to get result from database and convert to JSON.

```
   i=0
    a = []
    for food in sorted_similar_food:
        if i==0:
            i = i+1
        else:
            name = get_title_from_index(food[0])
            name = str(name)
            db_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM recipe where name = " + "'" + name + "'")
            r = [dict((db_cursor.description[i][0], value)
                    for i, value in enumerate(row)) for row in db_cursor.fetchall()]
            a.append( r)
    return jsonify({'cursor': a})
```

AND my result JSON

```
{ "cursor": [
    [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "image": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cricket-17449.appspot.com/o/manti.jpg?alt=media&token=d11a65ec-6486-4b24-a54a-2840ce4fdc",
        "ind": "kiyma yumurta sogan un",
        "name": "manti",
        "recip": "Ge"
      }
    ],
....
]}
```

There are two brackets. I want to one of them. I should remove one of them.

Comment: İn json result. There are 2 braackets after cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with an empty list `a=[]`. Inside your loop, you `append` a list of DB results (`r` is another list). What you want to do is `a.extend(r)`. That way the elements inside `r` are appended to `a` and you end up with just the `a` list.

Comment: Thank you very much!